# Query evaluation with "INTERSECT" function

Tags: sql, evaluation, intersect

I've a query:

```
QUERY1{statements...} 
INTERSECT
QUERY2{statements...}
```

I need to evaluate these 2 queries according to giving database data,
 **my question is:**
do I have to evaluate each query separately and then combine the 2 results together? 
i.g: cost(Query1) + cost(Query2) = Total query's cost ? .. or there is another way to solve this?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `intersect`, so your query is not going to run.

Comment: It's not mySQL, sorry that was by mistake.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to add the 2 queries' cost.

In Toad Oracle you can evaluate the global intersect query:[image]